# create and mutate an object in one line

Tags: javascript, typescript

In this case I can't do

```
let firstDate = new Date().setDate(1) // returns a number, not the mutated Date object
```

I have to do

```
let firstDate = new Date();
firstDate.setDate(1);
```

Can I write the later in a more elegant way ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: `(firstDate = new Date()).setDate(1)` is a one-liner to create the object, keep a reference to it, *and* mutate it, but it only works if `firstDate` is already declared. (But since you've used `let` it could be assumed that you intend to reassign it after initial declaration, so...)

Answer (score 2):

```
(new Date()).setDate(1)
^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- reference to this gets lost.
```

You lose reference to the object you've created. If you really want to do it anyhow, try this:

```js
var date = new Date(new Date().setDate(1))
console.log(date);
```

Comment: @nnnnnn yeah i was just editing the post to add the working solution